# Cant import psycopg2

Tags: python

I am trying to install postgresql_python.
I downloaded the tarball and installed it using:
python setup.py build
python setup.py install

I got /usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/psycopg2/ with

```
> total 836
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12759 Dec 11 18:18 errorcodes.py
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14584 Dec 12 13:49 errorcodes.pyc
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14584 Dec 12 13:49 errorcodes.pyo
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5807 Dec 11 18:18 extensions.py
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7298 Dec 12 13:49 extensions.pyc
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7298 Dec 12 13:49 extensions.pyo
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  31495 Dec 11 18:18 extras.py
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  35124 Dec 12 13:49 extras.pyc
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  35124 Dec 12 13:49 extras.pyo
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6177 Dec 11 18:18 __init__.py
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5740 Dec 12 13:49 __init__.pyc
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5740 Dec 12 13:49 __init__.pyo
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8855 Dec 11 18:18 pool.py
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8343 Dec 12 13:49 pool.pyc
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8343 Dec 12 13:49 pool.pyo
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3389 Dec 21 11:17 psycopg1.py
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3182 Dec 21 11:22 psycopg1.pyc
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3167 Dec 12 13:49 psycopg1.pyo
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 572648 Dec 21 11:22 _psycopg.so drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Dec 21 10:38 tests
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4427 Dec 11 18:18 tz.py
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4325 Dec 12 13:49 tz.pyc
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4325 Dec 12 13:49 tz.pyo
```

But in python shell when I am trying to import library, I got error:

```
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 76, in ?
    from psycopg2._psycopg import _connect, apilevel, threadsafety, paramstyle
ImportError: cannot import name _connect
```

I am running with Postgresql 9.2.

What am I missing here?
Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have to remove some existing packages related to psycopg2 within your root. Some common locations:

```
rm -r /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/psycopg2*
rm -r /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/psycopg2*
```

However, I recommend setting up a virtualenv to house the packages for your Python app.

Check out [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). It's easy to use once installed:

```
virtualenv myapp
. myapp/bin/activate
cd ~/your/postgres_lib/download
python setup.py install
```

This will install postgres libraries into your virtualenv (located under the `myapp`) folder. Then, whenever you want to run your app, you just need to activate the environment via

```
. myapp/bin/activate
```

Adjusting the path to `myapp` when necessary. There are helpers, like [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) to streamline this process.

Comment: Thanks, I removed all the old files and installed it again and now it works.